# Subclassing User to differentiate between an admin and an App with an API key?

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-authentication, django-rest-framework

This is my first API, so please forgive/correct me if I make any wrong claims.

I have an app that has an API. I would only like external apps (mobile clients etc.) with a valid API key to have access to it, and I think django-rest-framework's TokenAuthentication is the right fit for it. I would also like users to be able to log in with their username & password, and I'm looking to use OAuth2Authentication for that. But I don't want apps that use TokenAuthentication to have a "User" instance in the database (as they are not users in the traditional sense) so I'm thinking about doing something like this:

```
class Client(User):
    pass
```

1. django-rest-framework says that request.user will be an instance of User. Will I bump into any problems if I use Client instead?
2. Is this the standard way of handling this situation? It just doesn't feel right to me (mainly because of question 1)

Answer (score 0):

For mobile clients to have access to your API, using django-restframework's TokenAuthentication will work just fine. As you have already ascertained. You need to design a mechanism for handing out your tokens. If you are doing this dynamically then you will need to have your API request handle this.

**Mobile Client: ( initial API request )**

1. request /API/rabbit/1/
2. ( no token)

**Server: 401**

1. test for the token ( fails )
2. 'login please' via HTTP 401 response. ( or some other custom header or response information )

You can define your api on how to accomplish this, most folks use the http: 
 [401 Unauthorized](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) error code. I point this out because its clearly a design decision.

**Mobile Client: ( request login)**

1. prompts user for username and password, and makes a request too /login/ this could be a special mobileclient login like /mobile/login/ whose difference is that it hands back a token on a successful login.

**Server: 200**

1. verifies valid user and hands out token.
   you could write this logic, or you could use 'rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token' which I recommend. See rest-frameworks 
   [token authentication](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication) for details on this. Heed its warning about https.

**Mobile Client: ( re-request API with token in http header)**

1. receives token
2. now remakes initial request to /API/rabbit/1/ with its token in the header.

**Server: 200**

1. verifies valid token in the header and provides access to API. You will be writing this code.

**Finally:** You will need to design a strategy to 'age-out' your tokens, and or lock out users.

**Also:** make sure you add 'rest_framework.authtoken' to your INSTALLED_APPS, and make sure you call `manage.py syncdb`

**Aside:** you do not specifically have to use the TokenAuthentication ( request.user, request.auth) you can write your own code to peek in the header and see if the token is set. This is fairly easy to do with the python Cookie lib. You are still using-heavly the token management features of django-rest-framework. To be honest I think there documentation is a bit incomplete on configuring the 'TokenAuthentication' authentication back-ends.

Hope this helps!